# Meteor: Cannot find module 'angular'

Tags: node.js, meteor, heroku, angular-material, angular-meteor

I'm newbie on Meteor.

After one week on it, and started by implementing the todo of the tutorial as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), every things was good locally.

> just the fact that I'm continually trying to deploy it, but my heroku
>   link(https://tasktor.herokuapp.com) just show a blank page with
>   the this error in de debugger:

```
Error: angular@^1.2.27 not installed. tmeasday_check-npm-versions.js:66:11
Error: Cannot find module 'angular'
```

> Note that everything is clean on http://localhost:3000.

Already try a lot of solutions, as:

> - meteor add angular
> - meteor npm install --save angular
> - Disable minification of Js and Css.

This is the repository of this app deployed to heroku: https://github.com/dassiorleando/tasktor

his buildpack: https://github.com/dassiorleando/heroku-buildpack-meteor,
it is a buildpack with an updated Node Engine(4.5.0), that allowed to run an app with the meteor 1.4.X version.

Knowing that I add Angular-Material after finish this tutorial, because I wanted to have a clean material design style on my todo. You can check the repository to look about.
How can I handle this situation ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this:

```
meteor add angular
```

Adds an old atmosphere angular-meteor package, which also refers to an old (1.2.27) version of angular. The best way to proceed is to remove this and just use angular npm packages. You will need these packages

```
pbastowski:angular-babel
urigo:static-templates
dotansimha:accounts-ui-angular
```

The last one is if you are using the accounts package.

The tutorial at https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/bootstrapping recommends this:

> So let's remove it by running:
>
> ```
> $ meteor remove blaze-html-templates
> $ meteor remove ecmascript
> ```
>
> Now let's add the Angular 1 package to Meteor, back in the command
>   line, launch this command:
>
> ```
> $ meteor npm install --save angular angular-meteor babel-runtime
> $ meteor add angular-templates pbastowski:angular-babel
> ```
>
> That's it! Now we can use Angular 1's power in our Meteor app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mikkel. Please, did you test it with the code hosted in github ??

https://github.com/dassiorleando/tasktor

Comment: I changed the packages as per the tutorial's suggestion, and it runs fine locally. I don't have access or experience with heroku, although it appears like a black box anyway. In the angular-accounts-ui package there is a dependency on angular 1.2.27 or greater, which shouldn't be a problem. I think something in the heroku buildpack is interpreting this the wrong way - maybe you could take it up with the package maintainer?

Comment: Ok It is also working locally for me.
Thanks for your suggestion, I will do it.